# How to create a private channel only the user and the bot can see in Discord.js v14?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to create a private channel in Discord.js v14 but my code returns an error.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```js
else if (interaction.customId === 'donatid') {
    if(interaction.values[0] == '01'){
     const everyoneRole = interaction.guild.roles.everyone;
     const name = interaction.user.tag;
     interaction.guild.channels.create(name, 'text') // i think problem over here
     .then(r => {
         r.overwritePermissions(interaction.author.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
         r.overwritePermissions(client.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
         r.overwritePermissions(everyoneRole, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
       })
   .catch(console.error);

   }
};
```

And the error:

```
DiscordAPIError\[50035\]: Invalid Form Body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code. In v14, [`create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.6.0/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) accepts an `options` object and `"text"` is not a valid type anymore. You should import the `ChannelType` enums and use `ChannelType.GuildText` for this.

There is no `interaction.author`. There is an `interaction.user` or an `interaction.member`, so you can use those if you want to use the author's ID.

There is no `client.id` either. You can grab the bot's ID, using `client.user.id` though.

Also, you could add the permissions inside the `create` method as an option so you don't have to use that `then`. See the working code below:

```js
const { ChannelType, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

//...
  interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: interaction.user.tag,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
        deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      },
      {
        id: interaction.user.id,
        allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      },
      {
        id: client.user.id,
        allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
      },
    ],
  });
```